# Late 50's movie episode about a man who finds a pair of old glasses that enable him to read others thoughts

Tags: story-identification, horror, urban-fantasy

I'm trying to identify a movie episode I watched in the around the late '50s, about a man who finds a pair of old glasses which enable him to read the thoughts of other people.

Reading others thoughts turns out badly because the man's wife is hiding financial information from him, as well as having an affair with his work helper in his junk business.

Bad things happen and the glasses are passed on more than once.

The wife character is the one I remember best because she plays the evil cheating, lying, complaining wife so brilliantly.

Comment: Is my answer correct?

Comment: @FeyRay: Just pinging you, is Obie 2.0's answer correct?

Answer (score 6):

### This is [*Thriller*: "The Cheaters"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0723094/)

In this episode, **aired in 1960**, a man [develops glasses that can see people's thoughts](http://athrilleraday.blogspot.com/2010/09/cheaters-season-1-episode-15.html):

> Dirk Van Prinn (Henry Daniell) creates a special pair of spectacles:
>   when donned, they reveal the truth in others.

According to the writer at the end of the episode:

> "I believe that these spectacles enable the wearer to know the naked, absolute truth about anything and anybody."

His wife has a lover. [From the same article](http://athrilleraday.blogspot.com/2010/09/cheaters-season-1-episode-15.html):

> I have trouble suspending my disbelief when other characters start to
>   carry on conversations in their innermost thoughts the way Joe
>   Henshaw's wife (Linda Watkins) does with her secret beau, Charlie (Ed
>   Nelson).

Bad things certainly do happen. As the writer says:

> "These are not ordinary glasses. I'm convinced that because these
>   spectacles were misused, five people met violent deaths."